# Error when creating or editing Products: magesetup/source_revocationProductType not found for attribute "revocation_product_type"

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, error, eav

I have the following error when creating / editing Products:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:120:"Quellen-Modell "magesetup/source_revocationProductType" not found for attribute "revocation_product_type" in app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Quellen-Modell ...')
```

The full trace:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:120:"Quellen-Modell "magesetup/source_revocationProductType" wurde nicht gefunden für das Attribut "revocation_product_type"";i:1;s:3616:"#0 /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Quellen-Modell ...')
#1 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Attributes.php(70): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Array)
#3 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php(79): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#8 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#9 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#10 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#11 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#12 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#13 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#14 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(Array, true, true)
#15 /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(207): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout(Array)
#16 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->newAction()
#17 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('new')
#18 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}";s:3:"url";s:96:"/index.php/admin/catalog_product/new/set/4/type/simple/key/f7ed55518848130fb6fee36d50ddccf6/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

I can't think of when or why this may have happened.

How do I go about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you probably had an extension installed that added an attribute with a custom source model and that model class does not exist anymore.
Search in the table `eav_attribute` for a record with `source_model = 'magesetup/source_revocationProductType'`.  Remove the records you find and clear the cache. A reindex would not hurt either.

Comment: Thanks Marius, that was a fast response! =) This seems to have fixed the issue. I'll accept your answer in 6 minutes when it lets me.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction! otherwise i'd be looking for a needle in a haystack

Answer (score 1):

It's a `FireGento_MageSetup` module's error. This extension uses `magesetup/source_revocationProductType` type.

You can disable it from `/app/etc/modules` directory